# Change default Database in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I'm working on C# Winform app and I have the query that select the list of tables but in but in the schema of the user I list there's no table listed.

This query should work in SQL Server

```
ALTER LOGIN [my_user_name] WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE = [new_default_database]
```

is there query like that on oracle?

Comment: Oracle has no notion of a "default database". If you don't see any tables, you are probably connecting as the wrong user.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, there's not (as far as I can tell).

> (Just a side note: what you call "database" in MS SQL Server is called "user" in Oracle, while "schema" = "user + all its objects").

Solution? Connect as user which owns tables you use.

Alternatively, if you can't have those credentials (username and password + database) for some reasons (such as security), you'll have to get access to those objects, somehow. One option is that owner grants (at least) `select` privilege. Suppose I'm the owner (user = "littlefoot"):

```
grant select on employees to kim;
```

("kim" is user you can connect to).

Then you'd precede table name with owner name:

```
select * From littlefoot.employees;
```

Or, you could create a synonym to all those tables so that you could avoid specifying owner name:

```
create synonym employees for littlefoot.employees;
select * from employees;
```

Or, if it really is a different database, you'll have to create a database link, but it presumes that you know login credentials so - I believe that this is not your case.

Comment: I would say a database in SQL Server is called a (pluggable) database in Oracle. SQL Server's schema do map to Oracle's schema with the exception that a schema and a user are essentially the same thing in Oracle, but not in SQL Server

Comment: That may  be true, @a_horse. I can't argue as I know absolutely nothing about MS SQL Server, except what I read on forums so - at least in previous versions - people called "database" what is "user" in Oracle. Maybe things have changed, I really can't tell. Thank you for the comment. (Just to mention: it is a "p**L**uggable database :)).

Comment: The hierarchy is the same in both systems: an "instance" can contain multiple databases. And a "database" can contain multiple schemas (=users in Oracle). But you are right insofar that very often logical separation of tables done with databases in SQL Server is better mapped to users/schemas in Oracle as you can't (easily) have cross-database queries as you do in SQL Server.